# Google bot can't fetch some text from my blog

Tags: html, wordpress

when i see my website from spider's view http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/spider/index.php

There are very less number of words count, its not fetching my links as a text.
my blog address is zemtv .com

and when i perform same operation with my other site dramasonline .com

then its fetching links as text

Please suggest me what to do

Answer (score 0):

It is provably because the links in the your first website contain the attribute `rel="bookmark"`, while the second don't.

I would check the website also using the "fetch as Google" tool that available in the Webmaster Tools website.

Comment: links on the right side of zemtv. com under "user videos" are without rel="bookmark"

Comment: Did Googlebot visit your webpage again since you removed "rel=bookmark"? Google does not always update its database immediately, sometimes you need to wait weeks to see the changes appear in Google searches.

Comment: I want my site to show text to bots so i want to show the text on this http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/spider/index.php